# Re-organizing, regrouping, and reducing redundancy in R

Tags: r, time-series, data-manipulation, tapply

I have data that looks like this:

```
Hours<-c(.25,.5,.5,.5,.25,.5, 1, .5)
WaterYear<-rep(2013:2014,each = 4); WaterYear
Events0<-c(1,0,2,2,2,0,3,3)
Events1<-c(0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0)
Events2<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
df<-data.frame(WaterYear, Hours,Events0,Events1, Events2);df
```

I want to sum up hours by event groups for each of the three modeling scenarios, columns Events0, Events1, Events2.

So far, I've used tapply to create single tables:

```
df2<-tapply(df$Hours, list(df$Events0, df$WaterYear), sum)
df2<-df2[-c(1), ]
```

This gives me the right values for scenario Events0, however, I'd like a single table that looks something like the one below with all of the information summarized together.

```
Event   Hours   Year    Level
1       0.25    2013    Events0
2       1.00    2013    Events0
3       0.25    2014    Events0
4       1.50    2014    Events0
1       0.50    2013    Events1
2       1.00    2014    Events1
1       0.50    2013    Events2
2       1.00    2014    Events2
```

I also have dozens of events, so I'd like some code that doesn't require so much repetition.

Any help would be appreciated. Additionally, if you have suggestions on better search terms to use so that I can find the answer to this question, if already answered, that would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

One can try using `tidyr::gather` to convert data in long format. Afterwards group on `Level`, `Event` and `WaterYear` to summaries the data for `Hours`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% gather(Level, Event, - "Hours",   -"WaterYear") %>%
  filter(Event != 0) %>%
  group_by(Level, Event, WaterYear) %>%
  summarise(Hours = sum(Hours)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  select(Event,   Hours,   WaterYear,    Level)

#   Event Hours WaterYear   Level
# 1     1  0.25      2013 Events0
# 2     2  1.00      2013 Events0
# 3     2  0.25      2014 Events0
# 4     3  1.50      2014 Events0
# 5     1  0.50      2013 Events1
# 6     2  1.00      2014 Events1
# 7     1  1.00      2014 Events2
```